# Excel VBA: update cells with new content from textbox

Tags: excel, row, insert-update, vba

I have a long row of data split into cells. Each cell populates a textbox, and I have 20 textboxes (and by assumption I have 20 cells).

The code below is how I populate each textbox...

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Set rng = Worksheets("Risk&Issues").Range("A4")
i = 0: j = 1

txtbox_revri_idnum.Text = rng.Offset(i).Value
txtbox_revri_projname.Text = rng.Offset(i, j).Value: j = j + 1
txtbox_revri_isrefnum.Text = rng.Offset(i, j).Value: j = j + 1
...
txtbox_revri_projname.SetFocus
```

On the form I have an 'update' button which when pressed updates the cells (within the worksheet) with new content from each textbox. The code for the 'update' button is below...

```
Private Sub button_revri_update_Click()

ActiveCell.Value = txtbox_revri_projname.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = txtbox_revri_isrefnum.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = txtbox_revri_riskrefnum.Value
...
End Sub
```

When I view the worksheet, what I expect to see is an update to each cell which is populating a textbox. However, what I actual get is a new row inserted from wherever I happen to press the mouse on a cell.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you press "next" as shown in the previous question, the value of `i` is already set. Based on that question, you can use this

```
Private Sub button_revri_update_Click()
    j = 1

    rng.Offset(i).Value = txtbox_revri_projname.Text
    rng.Offset(i, j).Value = txtbox_revri_isrefnum.Text: j = j + 1:
    rng.Offset(i, j).Value = txtbox_revri_riskrefnum.Text: j = j + 1
    rng.Offset(i, j).Value = TextBox4.Text: j = j + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: I've built on the code above and found that when I update the row, the textboxes do not update the associated cells. Do I have my reference/pointers incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Your code adds a new row at the active cell ("wherever I happen to press the mouse") because you use ActiveCell.  Instead try something like:

```
Private Sub button_revri_update_Click()
Dim FirstRowCell as Range

Set FirstRowCell = ActiveSheet.Range("B1")
With FirstRowCell
   .Value = txtbox_revri_projname.Value
   .Offset(0, 1) = txtbox_revri_isrefnum.Value
   .Offset(0, 2) = txtbox_revri_riskrefnum.Value
End With
...
End Sub
```